# How to enable multi-touch interaction in VTK (e.g. zoom in on stl by pinching)?

Tags: python, touch, vtk

I'm trying to make an stl viewer using vtk (9.2.6 in python 3.11.2), which will be part of a larger application. The application will run on a windows 10 pc with touchscreen but I cannot figure out how to enable zooming, rotating... by touch gestures, even when using [vtkInteractorStyleMultiTouchCamera](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkInteractorStyleMultiTouchCamera.html) .

When I just open e.g. google chrome on that pc, I can pinch zoom just fine so I'm quite certain the problem is not hardware related.

I used the [vtk MouseEvents example](https://examples.vtk.org/site/Python/Interaction/MouseEvents/) and modified it to see if the touch events are even being triggered.

When I use a mouse, I can get the LeftButtonPressEvent and MiddleButtonPressEvent fine but nonmatter what I do on the touchscreen, I cannot get the touch events e.g. PinchEvent to trigger.

Below is the code I used for testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import vtkmodules.vtkInteractionStyle
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import vtkmodules.vtkRenderingOpenGL2
from vtkmodules.vtkCommonColor import vtkNamedColors
from vtkmodules.vtkFiltersSources import vtkSphereSource
from vtkmodules.vtkInteractionStyle import vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera, vtkInteractorStyleMultiTouchCamera
from vtkmodules.vtkRenderingCore import (
    vtkActor,
    vtkPolyDataMapper,
    vtkRenderWindow,
    vtkRenderWindowInteractor,
    vtkRenderer
)


class MyInteractorStyle(vtkInteractorStyleMultiTouchCamera):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.AddObserver('LeftButtonPressEvent', self.left_button_press_event)
        self.AddObserver('MiddleButtonPressEvent', self.middle_button_press_event)
        self.AddObserver('MiddleButtonReleaseEvent', self.middle_button_release_event)
        self.AddObserver('StartSwipeEvent', self.start_swipe_event)
        self.AddObserver('SwipeEvent', self.swipe_event)
        self.AddObserver('EndSwipeEvent', self.end_swipe_event)
        self.AddObserver('StartPinchEvent', self.start_pinch_event)
        self.AddObserver('PinchEvent', self.pinch_event)
        self.AddObserver('EndPinchEvent', self.end_pinch_event)
        self.AddObserver('StartRotateEvent', self.start_rotate_event)
        self.AddObserver('RotateEvent', self.rotate_event)
        self.AddObserver('EndRotateEvent', self.end_rotate_event)
        self.AddObserver('StartPanEvent', self.start_pan_event)
        self.AddObserver('PanEvent', self.pan_event)
        self.AddObserver('EndPanEvent', self.end_pan_event)
        self.AddObserver('TapEvent', self.tap_event)
        self.AddObserver('LongTapEvent', self.long_tap_event)

    def left_button_press_event(self, obj, event):
        print('Left Button pressed')
        self.OnLeftButtonDown()
        return

    def middle_button_press_event(self, obj, event):
        print('Middle Button pressed')
        self.OnMiddleButtonDown()
        return

    def middle_button_release_event(self, obj, event):
        print('Middle Button released')
        self.OnMiddleButtonUp()
        return

    def start_swipe_event(self, obj, event):
        print('start_swipe_event')
        return

    def swipe_event(self, obj, event):
        print('swipe_event')
        return

    def end_swipe_event(self, obj, event):
        print('end_swipe_event')

    def start_pinch_event(self, obj, event):
        print('start_pinch_event')

    def pinch_event(self, obj, event):
        print('pinch_event')

    def end_pinch_event(self, obj, event):
        print('end_pinch_event')

    def start_rotate_event(self, obj, event):
        print('start_rotate_event')

    def rotate_event(self, obj, event):
        print('rotate_event')

    def end_rotate_event(self, obj, event):
        print('end_rotate_event')

    def start_pan_event(self, obj, event):
        print('start_pan_event')

    def pan_event(self, obj, event):
        print('pan_event')

    def end_pan_event(self, obj, event):
        print('end_pan_event')

    def tap_event(self, obj, event):
        print('tap_event')

    def long_tap_event(self, obj, event):
        print('long_tap_event')


def main():
    colors = vtkNamedColors()

    source = vtkSphereSource()
    source.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)
    source.SetRadius(1)
    source.Update()

    mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())

    actor = vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)
    actor.GetProperty().SetColor(colors.GetColor3d('MistyRose'))

    renderer = vtkRenderer()
    renderer.SetBackground(colors.GetColor3d('SlateGray'))
    renderer.AddActor(actor)

    renwin = vtkRenderWindow()
    renwin.AddRenderer(renderer)
    renwin.SetWindowName('MouseEvents')

    interactor = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    interactor.SetInteractorStyle(MyInteractorStyle())

    interactor.SetRenderWindow(renwin)

    interactor.Initialize()
    renwin.Render()
    interactor.Start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```